# Is Stack Exchange working on providing a GraphQL based API endpoint?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump, api

GitHub currently offers both REST API and a GraphQL endpoint to query its entire database. I was wondering if Stack Exchange (SE) is working on offering a GraphQL endpoint sometime soon.

As a consumer of these APIs, and having just gotten started with GraphQL, I can say that GraphQL offers a unique set of features and faster querying (in terms of logic and thinking what data you want to get; I am not so sure about how fast it is in actually returning the data.)

Also, SE also releases a data dump of every site every quarter, and the data can also be queried online. Are there any plans of offering a GraphQL endpoint for that data as well? I would be willing to contribute towards implementing that, if need be.

This will be great for research and mining SE data (specifically, Stack Overflow, for software development), and I think it must be implemented.

Comment: Stack Exchange seems to have "locked off" API development and doesn't respond to some serious API  bugs.  It seems unlikely that they'd be working on a GraphQL interface.

Comment: I wish we could develop it ourselves.

Comment: Actually, that might be a permitted use of the data dump (haven't double-checked in a while) that you *could* develop.

Comment: Let's confirm that!